# Kill Boost thread with another timeout thread

Tags: multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I want to end a thread `WorkerThread` after a certain amount of time has elapsed.
I was thinking to use a second thread `TimeoutThread` for this, that changes a flag after 15 seconds so the other thread stops.
Is there a more elegant way in boost to do this?

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

struct MyClass
{
    boost::thread timeoutThread;
    boost::thread workerThread;
    bool btimeout = true;

    void run()
    {
     timeoutThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::TimeoutThread, this));
      workerThread  = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::WorkerThread, this));
     workerThread.join();
     TimeoutThread.join();
    }


    void WorkerThread() {

        while(boost::this_thread::interruption_requested() == false && btimeout) 
        {
            printf(".");

        }
    }

    void TimeoutThread() 
    {
        boost::this_thread::disable_interruption oDisableInterruption;
        DWORD nStartTime = GetTickCount();

        while(boost::this_thread::interruption_requested() == false) 
        {
            if(GetTickCount() - nStartTime > 15)
            {
                m_bTimeout = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass x;
    x.run();
}
```

Comment: Why did you "mutilate" the code so that it can't compile? It's so close to being selfcontained, but then you removed the class, mistyped `MyClass bTimeout`, bound extraneous this pointers that don't exist etc. In that case, better to keep the class, because I just had to recreate it in order to compile...

Comment: Also, it seems you removed the `join()` on the timeout thread just now, please be aware that this is now invalid; all threads must be joined or detached before application termination

Comment: lol at the edit :/ It still says `MyClass btimeout;` and you're still binding `this` in main... _Never mind_. See my answer for SSCCE by now (and the comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sleep:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

struct MyClass
{
    boost::thread timeoutThread;
    boost::thread workerThread;

    void TimeoutThread() {
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(15));
        workerThread.interrupt();
    }

    void WorkerThread() {
        while(!boost::this_thread::interruption_requested())
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        timeoutThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::TimeoutThread, this));
        workerThread  = boost::thread(boost::bind(&MyClass::WorkerThread, this));
        workerThread.join();
        timeoutThread.join();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass x;
    x.run();
}
```

This has the minimal benefit of being portable.

See it **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ad8f9a2ac679949e)**

Please be aware of the `deadline_timer` class in Boost Asio too.

And it looks like you're trying to await a condition in your worker thread. If so, you can also await a `condition_variable` with a deadline (`cv.wait_until` or with a timeout: `cv.wait_for`).

Comment: Thanks! That would probably work, but I am using boost 1.49.0 and this only seems to work in the trunk version I suppose.

Comment: I use 1_55 but AFAIR it's been in earlier versions

Comment: @tzippy Also, here's the equivalent std c++11: **[std=c++11 only](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec18be849ff68565)** and the equivalent **[in boost only](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28a250f23e34852a)**. This shouldn't require anything "new" or "fancy".

Comment: @tzippy did you get my comment ^ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just check time in worker thread and you won't need a separate *timeout* thread:

```
void WorkerThread() 
{
    DWORD nStartTime = GetTickCount();
    while(boost::this_thread::interruption_requested() == false && GetTickCount() - nStartTime < 15000) 
    {
        printf(".");

    }
}
```

BTW, please note `15000`, because GetTickCount() units are **milliseconds**

Comment: Why would we assume that he didn't _want_ **milliseconds**?

Comment: @sehe: "that changes a flag after 15 **seconds**", of course this could be a mistake too :)

Comment: Ahaha. I missed that :)