# Worker and interrupter thread coordination in Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

Kind of C++ and even more Boost noobie here.
I have successfully managed to create two threads, based on this  [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763146/kill-boost-thread-with-another-timeout-thread), one Worker and one Interrupter. The latter sleeps, via this_thread::sleep_for for 50 seconds and interrupts the Worker if he is not done within that time, with proper use of while !this_thread::interruption_requested() and thread::interrupt(). So it's a very nice and easy timeout mechanism. My problem is how to stop Interrupter sleep sooner? I mean if Worker finishes before that 50 seconds, I do a this_thread::yield or this_thread::interruption_requested (both seem to work) but Interrupter is still asleep and have to wait for 50 seconds for him to wake up:(

Is there any way to do this timeout mechanism, but if Worker is done with his work before sleep is over, to notify/wake up Interrupter?

PS: Do I need some sort of synchronization when all are done?

Comment: Your interrupter thread should not sleep unconditionally for 50 seconds but wait for conditional variable for 50 seconds, if worker thread finishes earlier it will signal conditional var and interrupter would wake up

Comment: Hmmm great idea, but how can you sleep conditionally?

Comment: Look at boost or std conditional variable API, it has wait with timers

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for,  boost API is the same

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will keep posted on my progress

Comment: I can convert that to an answer if it works for yoy

Comment: Yes it worked fine, please convert it to an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interrupter thread should not sleep unconditionally for 50 seconds but wait for conditional variable for 50 seconds, if worker thread finishes earlier it will signal conditional var and interrupter would wake up. You can use either [std::conditional_variable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) or one from boost with the same name